# Reading floats inside strings from a file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have a text file like this:

```
"-3.588920831680E-02","1.601887196302E-01","1.302309112549E+02"
"3.739478886127E-01","1.782759875059E-01","6.490543365479E+01"
"3.298096954823E-01","6.939357519150E-02","2.112392578125E+02"
"-2.319437451661E-02","1.149862855673E-01","2.712340698242E+02"
"-1.015115305781E-01","-1.082316488028E-01","6.532022094727E+01"
"-5.374089814723E-03","1.031072884798E-01","5.510117187500E+02"
"6.748274713755E-02","1.679160743952E-01","4.033969116211E+02"
"1.027429699898E-01","1.379162818193E-02","2.374352874756E+02"
"-1.371455192566E-01","1.483036130667E-01","2.703260498047E+02"
"NULL","NULL","NULL"
"3.968210220337E-01","1.893606968224E-02","2.803018188477E+01"
```

I tried to read this textfile using numpy as:

```
dat = np.genfromtxt('data.txt',delimiter=',',dtype='str')
print("dat = {}".format(dat))

# now when I try to convert to float
dat = dat.astype(np.float) # it fails

# try to make it float
dat = np.char.strip(dat, '"').astype(float)
```

> ```
> File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
>     dat = dat.astype(np.float)  # it fails
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"-3.588920831680E-02"'
> ```

How can I fix this error?

Related links:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt

Comment: You should provide a summary of what each of those links taught you and why it didn't work. otherwise why did you bother posting them?

Comment: Hi Mad man, I have commented each time why it failed in the updated code. The numpy solution fails, I can do it using pandas and using normal python (somewhat long and many lines) but I can not do it using numpy method. Thanks for suggestions though.

Comment: how exactly does `dat.astype(np.float)` fail?

Comment: It says it cant convert NULL to floats.

Comment: `dat = np.char.replace(dat, 'NULL',np.nan).astype(float)`  This also fails

Comment: How? "it fails" is not acceptable as a standalone statement.

Comment: Dr. Physicist, apologies for a simple question. I thought since I got the problem with numpy reading file and if anybody else gets the same problem, then by reading this post they might  benefit, which is the sole purpose I posted the question. Ultimately I figured out the solution. Thanks for the help and criticism. Good night.

Comment: does it actually have quotes around everything?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unfortunately Yes. For those curious, this the output obtainedfitsfile reader " FV-viewer"  output text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read that file directly using the `csv` module like:

#### Code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

reader = csv.reader(open('file1'), delimiter=",")
data = np.array([[float(i) if i != 'NULL' else np.nan for i in row]
                  for row in reader])

print(data)
```

#### Results:

```
[[ -3.58892083e-02   1.60188720e-01   1.30230911e+02]
 [  3.73947889e-01   1.78275988e-01   6.49054337e+01]
 [  3.29809695e-01   6.93935752e-02   2.11239258e+02]
 [ -2.31943745e-02   1.14986286e-01   2.71234070e+02]
 [ -1.01511531e-01  -1.08231649e-01   6.53202209e+01]
 [ -5.37408981e-03   1.03107288e-01   5.51011719e+02]
 [  6.74827471e-02   1.67916074e-01   4.03396912e+02]
 [  1.02742970e-01   1.37916282e-02   2.37435287e+02]
 [ -1.37145519e-01   1.48303613e-01   2.70326050e+02]
 [             nan              nan              nan]
 [  3.96821022e-01   1.89360697e-02   2.80301819e+01]]
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your floating point number is being enclosed by 2 quotes instead of 1. Numpy wants your array to have strings like

`'1.45E-02'`

Instead you have something like

`' "1.45E-02" '`(Note the extra double quotes at the beginning and end).

So the solution to this problem will be simply to remove those extra double quotes which can be done quite easily as follows:

```
dat_new = np.char.replace(dat,'"','')
dat_new = np.char.replace(dat_new,'NULL','0') #You also need to do something 
#with NULL. Here I am just replacing it with 0.
dat_new = dat_new.astype(float)
```

`np.char.replace(np_array,string_to_replace,replacement)` essentially works as 'Find and Replace'  and replaces each instance of your second argument with the third.